# Click twice to populate two hidden fields with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have two JS functions in an attempt to populate two hidden fields during the button onclick event. I am getting inconsistent results.  Here are the JS functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Short()
    {
        var text = document.getElementById('LongPost').value
        document.getElementById('ShortPost').value = text.substring(0, 100)
        alert(document.getElementById('ShortPost').value)
    }

    function UpdateDT()
    {
        document.getElementById('Update').value = new Date()
    }
</script>
```

then in the button onclick, I am calling both:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Short(); UpdateDT()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

`UpdateDT()` is working fine.  `Short()` does not.  I inserted an `alert()` to test the output and when I click, the alert is empty.  If I click it a second time, there is data in the alert but the text box doesn't populate.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: It's working for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh6w78nt/

Comment: @KennethK. i'm confused, this isn't a console app.  Are you talking about the Output window?

Comment: can you please make sure your html contains elements with LongPost, ShortPost and Update ids?

Comment: @SwaroopDeval I did confirm.  thank you.

Comment: @Natixco, yes, I tested it in jsfiddle to make sure it wasn't a syntax problem.

Comment: The browser console (e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console).

Comment: @KennethK. thank you.  I've used the Elements but not the Console.  I'm trying to write some values out but not having much luck.  I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Ok...I forgot to mention I was using the TinyMCE rich text editor.  I removed that and the onclick works as expected.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

here, working code sample

```
        <asp:Label ID="ShortPost" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Update" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Short(); UpdateDT(); return false;" />
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function Short() {
        var text = $("#LongPost").text();
        $("#ShortPost").text(text.substring(0, 4)); 
    }

    function UpdateDT() {
        $("#Update").text(new Date());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nasira, thank you for the response.  I neglected to update the thread that because I was using TinyMCE I needed to call that object to get the value rather than the text box.  TinyMCE replaces the text box which is why I was getting inconsistent results.  Thank you!